# Sending data, Class, and Method through Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

How can I send data through ajax to a specific method in a another PHP class? In the `url` value I have pointed to the class file, but where can I assign the method name to use?

```
$.ajax({    

        type:'POST',
        url:'ResortController.php',
        data: vidData, 
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(vidData);
            //window.location.reload();         
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the data in `data:vidData` and specify your function name after call of controller.

```
url = BASE_PATH + 'ResortController/FUNCTION_NAME';
vidData = {id: 123, vidName: "testVideo"};

$.ajax({    
        type:'POST',
        url:url,
        data: vidData, 
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
            //window.location.reload();         
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

Using `$_POST` in your function you will get your ajax data in `$_POST['vidData']`.

Also you need to call `data` instead of `vidData` variable in success of ajax `console.log(data)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a server-side mechanism in place to handle how to direct your requests. Presumably the url you are sending a request to just has the class declaration...you need some sort of dispatcher or else php doesn't know what to do:

**jQuery:**

```
$.ajax({  
        type:'POST',
        url:'/dispatcher.php',
        data: {
            "data":vidData,
            "class":"ResortController",
            "method":"rMethod"
        },
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(vidData);
            //window.location.reload();         
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

**/dispatcher.php**

```
<?php
// This is dangerous if you have no controls in place to allow/restrict
// a program to run a command
// Anyone could send a cURL request and run an automated class/method through
// this mechanism unless you have some way to restrict that
if(!empty($_POST['class']) && !empty($_POST['method'])) {
    // Here you want to have some way to check that a request is valid and not 
    // made from some outside source to run arbitrary commands
    // I will pretend you have an admin identifier function....
    if(is_admin()) {
        call_user_func_array(array($_POST['class'],$_POST['method']),array('data'=>$_POST['data']));
    }
}
```